# Is using "as" in C# a safe way of casting?

Tags: c#, casting

I am wondering if using the keyword "as" in the following code is a safe way (i.e. won't blow up) of casting in C#:

```
public void abc(ref Object dataSource)
{
    DataTable table = dataSource as DataTable;
}
```

Is there a safer way of casting?

Comment: Why is dataSource passed by ref?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: dataSource (and thus table) is being used to hook up delegates. I feel like the address should be passed and not the value.. (if I'm understanding the point of ref and as well as delegates)...

Comment: And why do you feel that way? Do you ever mutate the variable that dataSource is aliasing? That's the point of "ref" -- to create an alias to a variable so that you can mutate it.

Comment: @Felice: I was under the assumption that if dataSource was not a table, it would blow up on the spot. (I was just wondering if there was a way it will not blow up) But now from the answers I realize that it will just return null (which is much nicer than blowing up right? :).

Comment: @developer: your use of "as" is appropriate if you are *genuinely unsure* whether the argument is a DataTable or not. However, if you need it to be a DataTable then why not simply make the argument require that you pass a DataTable, and put the burden on the caller?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, it is possible the table may mutate. I am doing the following: `table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler (handler.DataChanged);` which later on may affect the table by making some sort of change in the `DataChanged` function. Would you say that using `ref` is appropriate in that situation then?

Comment: @developer: Are you changing the *contents* of the table but keeping the reference to the table the same, or are you changing *the variable that refers to the table to refer to an entirely different table*?  In the former case, "ref" is unnecessary and confusing.  In the latter case, you'd use "ref". But a better practice in that case would be to *return* the new table.

Comment: @Eric: no I am using inheritance (this is a derived function) and each derived class is using a different data source so I cannot be sure.

Comment: Remember, objects of reference type are *already passed by reference*. That's why they're called "objects of reference type". A "ref" is a reference to *a variable*, not a reference to *an object*.

Comment: @Eric: I may be making changes to the contents of the table. I don't want second copies flying around and having people attempting to make changes but it not being reflected in the original. I think it will be safer to keep it as one and only one copy of the table (or xmlDocument in my other class).

Comment: Think about it this way:  "c = new Customer(); M(ref c); ... M(ref Customer x) { x = null; }" That makes x and c aliases for each other, so x = null is actually assigning c = null. Compare with "c = new Customer(); c.Name = "Bob"; M(c); ... M(Customer x) { x.Name = "Mary"; x = null; }"  M changes the value of c.Name because x and c refer to the same *customer*. But they do not refer to the same *variable*. When x is set to null, c keeps its value.

Comment: @developer: You are talking as though tables are value types. Tables are reference types. You don't get a copy of the *table* when you pass a table; you get a copy *of the reference*.  This is a fundamental concept in C#; you should learn how this works before you go any further.

Comment: @Eric: Okay thanks, I will read up on it more (i'll try Jon Skeet's article he listed)

Comment: @Eric: I read Jon's article, then I also read http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html - This helped a lot! I still want to use the `ref`.. I would like it to work like diagram #7.. (because if I implemented it like diagram #5, setting to the passed var to null would not change the original var.. which I feel could be important to be able to do).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It won't blow up... but that doesn't necessarily mean it's safe.

Typically when I use a cast for a reference conversion, it's because I *really, really* think that the execution-time type is the one I'm specifying. If it's not, that indicates a bug in my code - and I'd rather that manifested itself as an exception.

If you've got bad data in your system, then continuing as if everything was fine is the *dangerous* path, not the *safe* path. That's the way that `as` will take you, whereas a cast would throw an `InvalidCastException`, aborting whatever you're doing before you get the chance to cause mayhem with the bad data.

`as` is good if it's *valid* for the object not to be of the given type - if it doesn't indicate a bug. You *almost always* see the pattern of:

```
Foo x = y as Foo;
if (x != null)
{
    ...
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) for more details about what `as` does.

Note also that you *probably* don't want to use `ref` in your method. See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details. Most of the time if I see people using `ref` a lot, it's because they don't understand what it really means :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! (I need to read all of them before I decide on an answer though) As for the ref argument.. I am using dataSource (and thus table) for hooking up delegates: `table.RowChanged     += new DataRowChangeEventHandler    (handler.DataChanged);` Should this not be a ref (kind of the pointer in c++)? I figured it should be pointing to the address and not just giving the data table the value. But if I'm wrong.. please let me know :D

Comment: @developer: Read the article I linked to, basically. There's a big difference between "a reference" and "passing parameters by reference". *Don't* think in terms of C++ - it'll just confuse you when you're writing C#.

Comment: @Jon: I read your article, then I also read http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html - This helped a lot! I still want to use the `ref`.. I would like it to work like diagram #7.. (because if I implemented it like diagram #5, setting to the passed var to null would not change the original var.. which I feel could be important to be able to do).

Comment: @developer: Rather than use `ref`, consider introducing a return value. That's generally *much* clearer than using `ref`.

Comment: @Jon - I'm using a boolean as a return (which is a bool stating if the function was successful or not). So I wouldn't be able to do that. Why is it not considered "clean"?

Comment: @developer: Normally you should throw an exception instead of returning a status value... that's the idiomatic way of doing things.

Comment: @Jon: hmm.. well I'll see what I can do.. but it's been requested that I use bool to determine success AND use exception handling. :S

Comment: @developer: It's not really clear what you mean... you can't throw an exception *and* return a value. However, it sounds like your method may be trying to do too much... what's the real use case here?

Comment: @Jon: Maybe I'll create a new question in regards to this. I don't have a chance this afternoon but perhaps tomorrow morning. I'll provide a link to my question once I post. :) thanks for all your help/advice by the way.

Comment: @JonSkeet.your article on parameter passing is very helpful

Comment: There is an easier way now with C# 7. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295208/8259632

Comment: @AdamKingsley: Out of interest, did you realize you were linking to another of my own answers? :) I don't tend to go back over old answers to add new language features to them, simply because it would take all of my time...

Comment: @JonSkeet I did. :-) I linked to your answer so that you didn't need to update this answer. The other question will now show in the "linked" area.

Answer (score 20):

**It depends what you mean by "safe".** Ask yourself which is safer: an appliance with a circuit breaker, or one built without it? The one without a fuse is more likely to finish washing your clothes, but it's also more likely to burn your house down.

As you probably know, there are two main ways to do explicit casting in C#:

```
foo = (MyType)myObject;    //Cast myObject to MyType or throw an error
foo = myObject as MyType;  //Cast myObject to MyType or set foo to null
```

The difference is that if the runtime doesn't know how to cast `myObject` as `MyType`, the first line will throw an exception, while the second will only set `foo` to `null`. This would happen if the object living in `myObject` isn't a `MyType`, or if there's no explicit cast to `MyType` from whatever `myObject` is.

So which one is safer? Well, if "safe" means "won't throw an exception if the cast is invalid," then the `as` form is safer. If the casting fails, `(MyType)myObject` will blow up immediately, but `myObject as MyType` will only blow up if you try to do something to `foo` that you can't do to `null` (such as calling `foo.ToString()`).

On the other hand, **sometimes throwing an exception is the safest thing to do.** If you have a bug in your code, you probably want to know right away. If `myObject` is always expected to be a `MyType`, then a failed cast means there's a bug somewhere. If you carry on as though the casting worked, then all of a sudden your program is working with garbage data! It might blow up further down the line, making debugging difficult, or - worse - it might never blow up at all, just quietly do things you didn't expect. That could cause all kinds of havoc.

So neither form is inherently safe or correct, they're just useful for different things. You would use the `myObject as MyType` form if:

1. You don't know for sure what type `myObject` is
2. You want to do something with `myObject`, but only if it's of type `MyType`
3. `myObject` could be something other than `MyType`, and it won't mean there's a bug

One example is when you have a collection of different WebForm controls, and you want to clear all the TextBoxes among them:

```
foreach (var control in controls)
{
    var textbox = control as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null)
    {
        //Now we know it's a TextBox, so we know it has a Text property
        textbox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This way, your TextBoxes get cleared out, and everything else gets left alone.

Answer (score 5):

```
DataTable table = dataSource as DataTable;
```

Using `as` will return `null` if the cast is unsuccessful, so no it won't blow up. - that means you will have to handle the case that `table` is `null` in the rest of your code though.

Answer (score 4):

`as` won't blow up, but if the cast fails, the variable will be set to null.  You need to check for that case.

```
DataTable table = dataSource as DataTable;
if (table == null)
{
    // handle case here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It won't throw an exception, if that is what you mean by "safe". However, if the cast fails, `table` will be null.

```
DataTable table = dataSource as DataTable;
```

Does not throw an exception if the cast fails. Will be null instead.

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)dataSource;
```

Will throw an exception if the cast fails.

It's safe in that regard, however if it is possible for the cast to fail, then add a null check to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a safe way to cast in the fact that it won't cause an exception.  However, it can cause hidden bugs if you are not careful.

When using `as`, if the cast fails then the resulting variable is `null`.  If you don't check for this then you will later get a `NullReferenceException` when you attempt to access the variable, and it will be less clear on why it's failing (e.g. is it `null` because the cast failed or did something else later cause it to be null)

Answer (score 2):

The 'as' operator won't throw an exception if the cast is invalid.  It just returns null.  The () approach will throw an exception.  So to answer your question, it is the safest way.

Here is essentially the way you need to go about it:

```
if( x is MyType )
{
   MyType y = (MyType) x;
}
```

or

```
MyType y = x as MyType;
if( y != null )
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you're trying to do:

```
DataTable table = dataSource as DataTable;
if (table != null) ...
```

means "`dataSource` *might* be a `DataTable` and I'm going to check it's not `null`."

```
DataTable table = (DataTable) dataSource;
```

means "`dataSource` should *definitely* be a `DataTable` and something's badly wrong if it's not".

Answer (score 1):

The difference between using `as` and a normal cast is that if the cast can't be performed (because the object isn't the right type), the `as` operator will return `null`.  A normal cast will throw an exception.

So they're both "safe" - they just have different behaviors when the cast can't be successful.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe in the sense that it will get the job done if dataSource can be casted as a DataTable.  But if you are worried about it not casting successfully, you can first check if dataSource.GetType() is equal to the Type you are trying to cast it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use as, there won't be a runtime InvalidCastException, but table may be null, so you need to check for that.