# Safe casting in C++/CLI - equivalent to C#'s "as"?

Tags: c#, casting, c++-cli

Earlier I asked if using `as` in C# was safe (i.e. won't blow up): [Is using "as" in C# a safe way of casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388609/is-using-as-in-c-a-safe-way-of-casting)

I liked the answer and ended up using something based off of it:

```
Foo x = y as Foo;
if (x != null)
{
    ...
}
```

But now I am converting my C# code to C++/CLI (due to a dependance issue..) so questions is..

I'm looking for the C++/CLI equivalent to "as", that is safe and won't blow up at runtime if not correct type. Can anyone suggest a cast that meets my needs? (please provide an example if you can)

Thanks!

Comment: coud this old thread be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712845/c-cli-question-is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-c-is-keyword-or-do-i-have-to-u

Comment: Reflector just says `as` here... but then, I don't know C++/CLI ;p

Comment: @Marc: From your deleted answer, I think you were using MC++ mode, not C++/CLI.  Of course, Reflector's decompiler for C++/CLI has always trailed the more marketed languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++ way to do such a thing is `dynamic_cast`. I don't know if it's the same for managed references as unmanaged references, MSDN had very little information on it.

Comment: So dynamic_cast does not cause a runtime error but using safe_cast does? (see other answer's comment below)

Comment: dynamic_cast<> is as, safe_cast<> is is :)

Comment: @Hans: No, `safe_cast` is a [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)  C# `is` returns a boolean, completely different.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85af44e9

Answer (score 0):

you need something called RTTI enabled when compiling C++.
Then you can use `dynamic_cast` (gives null similar to `as`) and `typeid` (similar to `is`).