# Using "is" keyword with "null" keyword c# 7.0

Tags: c#, null, keyword, c#-7.0

Recently i find out, that the following code compiles and works as expected in VS2017. But i can't find any topic/documentation on this. So i'm curious is it legit to use this syntax:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new object();              
        Console.WriteLine(o is null);
        o = null;
        Console.WriteLine(o is null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

BTW this is not working in VS2015

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/ second section. It's related to pattern matching.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely valid. This uses the *pattern matching* feature of C# 7, which is available with `is` expressions and `switch/case` statements. (The fact that it requires C# 7 is why it isn't working for you in VS2015.) For example:

```
// Type check, with declaration of new variable
if (o is int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i * 10);
}
// Simple equality check
if (o is 5)  {}
```

Equality checks like the latter - particularly for `null` - aren't likely to be very useful for `is` pattern matching, but are more useful for switch/case:

```
switch (o)
{
    case int i when i > 100000:
        Console.WriteLine("Large integer");
        break;
    case null:
        Console.WriteLine("Null value");
        break;
    case string _:
        Console.WriteLine("It was a string");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Not really sure");
        break;
}
```

For more details of C# 7 features, see the [MSDN blog post by Mads Torgersen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/).

Comment: Oh, i got it. So it is something like a type checking, casting and comparison in one line.

Comment: @GorRustamyan: Pattern matching is currently mostly about type and equality checking, with guard clauses for switch/case, but it may well be expanded significantly over time.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is valid to write ***o is null***, but this is not equivalent to ***o == null***.
The code

```
static bool TestEquality(object value) => value == null;
```

compiles into following IL instructions.

```
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  ceq
  IL_0004:  ret
```

The pattern matching case compiled in following manner:

```
static bool TestPatternMatching(object value) => value is null;

  IL_0000:  ldnull
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  call       bool [System.Runtime]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
  IL_0007:  ret
```

So, pattern matching ***o is null*** is equivalent to

```
Object.Equals(value, null);
```

So, in most cases ***o is null*** and ***o == null*** will behave in same way. Except equality variant is a bit faster. **BUT!** Things will change dramatically, if we replace ***object*** with following class.

```
class TestObject
{
    public static bool operator ==(TestObject lhs, TestObject rhs) => false;
    public static bool operator !=(TestObject lhs, TestObject rhs) => false;
}
```

and methods with

```
static bool TestEquality(TestObject value) => value == null;
static bool TestPatternMatching(TestObject value) => value is null;
```

The pattern matching will stay same, but the equality variant will use following IL

```
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  call       bool PatternMatchingTest.TestObject::op_Equality(class PatternMatchingTest.TestObject, class PatternMatchingTest.TestObject)
  IL_0007:  ret
```

Here we can see, that *==* operator is using *TestObject*'s overload as expected. But ***o is null*** and ***o==null*** will give different results. So be careful using pattern matching *is* operator.

Comment: IL looks like it does exactly the same equality check. Can you explain the difference with respect to C#?

Comment: In example above, Pattern matching is equivalent of Object.Equals(value, null) method call, which will compare references. And value == null is equivalent of calling TestObject's equality static method - TestObject.==(value, null), which in general can do any crazy stuff. In example below it will always return false, even if "value" is null reference