# "object is null" expression gives an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I have the following code:

```
public static class ItemsHelper
{
    public static object product
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Items["product"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["product"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in a function, I have the following expression:

```
if (ItemsHelper.product is null) return false;
```

I tested in visual studio 2017 and it works fine, but i tested in two different computers that runs visual studio 2015 and it retrieves the following error:

> type expected )

Any one have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: `is null` is a C# 7 feature, of course it is absent in VS 2015

Comment: Why don't your write `ItemsHelper.product == null`?

Comment: @Sentry I could, but I'm trying to understand why this is happening

Comment: Detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295208/3214843).

Comment: And [why you shouldn't use it instead of `== null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332827/3214843)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`is null` is a C# 7 feature. You would need a C# 7 compatible compiler to make your code compile.

Visual Studio 2017 ships with a compatible one but for Visual Studio 2015 you need to update. Check this question for instructions on how to update: [How to use c#7 with Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015).

Comment: The `is` keyword is not a C# 7 feature, just the new usage of `is` for pattern matching.